# How to send an ics email attachment in calendar format using Java?

Tags: java, icalendar

I am trying to send an email attachment using java by ics. I need to send an attachment to invite members using java. Please help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using JAVA Mailler API. [Here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) you can find the detailed example to implement. And you can add ics file as an attachment to the mail.

Comment: Thank you @jitendra for helping me to find a way to fix my need.